# How to stop the cron job from running using gocron

Tags: go, cron

I have created two `api` to `start` and to `stop` the cron job. I am able to start the job every 5 second and stop it. But stop doesn't seem to work. I tried finding on net but unable to find the example to stop the job from getting executed. here.
`Stop is pause and start is start/resume`

How do I fix it?

**on start:**
`Running cron job...`

**on stop:**
`Cron job stopped`

**but on start again:**
Instead of resuming it will throw all the job that are supposed to be stopped. They all at once will be printed.

```
Running cron job...
Running cron job...
Running cron job...
Running cron job...

.
.
. (didn't stop should display only two println(prev + current one which just completed 5 sec) instead of multiple println)
```

```golang
package handler

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/go-co-op/gocron"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
)

type Scheduler struct {
    scheduler *gocron.Scheduler
    job       *gocron.Job
}

func (sch *Scheduler) StartSchedulerJob(c *gin.Context) {
    if sch == nil {
        log.Println("Scheduler not initialized")
        return
    }
    // If scheduler is not null and scheduler is running then create a new job
    if sch != nil && !sch.scheduler.IsRunning() {
        sch.job, _ = sch.scheduler.Every(5).Second().Do(func() {
            fmt.Println("Running cron job...") // main logic
        })
        sch.scheduler.StartAsync()
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Cron job started")
    } else {
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Cron job is already running")
    }

}

func (sch *Scheduler) StopSchedulerJob(c *gin.Context) {
    if sch.scheduler.IsRunning() {
        sch.scheduler.Stop()
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Cron job stopped")
    } else {
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "No active cron job to stop")
    }
}

func InitializeScheduler() *Scheduler {
    sch := gocron.NewScheduler(time.Local)
    return &Scheduler{
        scheduler: sch,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it via using the job param and this function `RemoveByReference`.

```
func (sch *Scheduler) StartSchedulerJob(c *gin.Context) {
    if sch == nil {
        log.Println("Scheduler not initialized")
        return
    }

    // If scheduler job is null and scheduler is not running then create a new job
    if sch.job == nil || !sch.scheduler.IsRunning() { // <------ here
        sch.job, _ = sch.scheduler.Every(2).Second().Do(func() {
            fmt.Println("Running cron job...") // main logic
        })
        sch.scheduler.StartAsync()

        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Cron job started")
    } else {
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Cron job is already running")
    }

}

func (sch *Scheduler) StopSchedulerJob(c *gin.Context) {
    if sch.scheduler != nil && sch.scheduler.IsRunning() {
        sch.scheduler.RemoveByReference(sch.job) // <------ here
        sch.job = nil // <---- here
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Cron job stopped")
    } else {
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "No active cron job to stop")
    }
}
```